# “Non-200 response code during CRC GET request”

Tags: php, http, twitter, webhooks

I want t register a webhook. I have this PHP code in my webhook endpoint URL:

```
<?php
// Example app consumer secret found in apps.twitter.com
const APP_CONSUMER_SECRET = 'xxx';
// Example token provided by incoming GET request
$token = $_GET['crc_token'];
/**
 * Creates a HMAC SHA-256 hash created from the app TOKEN and
 * your app Consumer Secret.
 * @param  token  the token provided by the incoming GET request
 * @return string
 */

function get_challenge_response($token) {
  $hash = hash_hmac('sha256', $token, APP_CONSUMER_SECRET, true);
  $response = array(
    'response_token' => 'sha256=' . base64_encode($hash)
  );
  return json_encode($response);
}
// prints result
echo get_challenge_response($token);
```

If I try it directly (with the browser itself, i.e.) I get this response:
`{"response_token":"sha256=VvHK6oEH4CHfnP9ImMmidtjTHGy48DuACxR6TSYyCcQ="}`

Which makes me think it works properly, I also receive a 200 status code. But when I try to call the Twitter API to register the webhook I always get this error message:

```
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "code": 214,
      "message": "Non-200 response code during CRC GET request (i.e. 404, 500, etc)."
    }
  ]
}
```

Whether I try it with Insomnia, Postman, or even the [Account Activity Dashboard](https://github.com/twitterdev/account-activity-dashboard). It makes no sense because if I go to my browser and go to my PHP script, I receive good response.

Anyone know what is going on and how can I fix it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Twitter is saying that your script is returning something other than a HTTP 200 response code. It might indicate there is an error happening during the Twitter request.

1. Make sure the webhook URL is correct.
2. Log the request coming from Twitter and make sure you are getting the expected input.
3. Check your logs for errors.
4. Try forcing the response code:

```php
http_response_code(200);
```